# How do I create multiple video popups with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, onclick, toggle, queryselector

The following is the code: There are two video links that pop up in the same video. How do I add a second video so that when I click on the bottom link the second video will pop up?

I think that I need to add a parameter to the function show ( ). Maybe create a separate class for each video for the "video" element. I would really appreciate any help on this task. Also please let me know if you know of an online source to learn about editing DOM elements, and common Javascript functions used for CSS webpages. Javascript such as classlist.toggle, onclick="show();" I do plan on doing a course video that covers Javascript, maybe "The Complete Javascript Course 2023: From Zero to Expert!" by Jonas Schmedtmann.

```
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Responsive Video Popups</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="home">      
      <a href="#" onclick="show();">Watch Video 1</a>      
      <a href="#" onclick="show();">Watch Video 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="popup">
      <video src="video.mp4" controls></video>
      <img src="close.png" onclick="show();" class="close" alt="">
    </div>
  </section>
  <script>
    function show(){
      var popup = document.querySelector(".popup");
      var video = document.querySelector("video");
      popup.classList.toggle("active");
      video.pause();
      video.currentTime = 0;
    }
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>

CSS

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.home {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.home a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.popup video {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 900px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  max-width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: invert(1);
}

.popup.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: pass an argument to `show()` ... change `function show` to accept an argument ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="home">      
      <a href="#" onclick="show(1);">Watch Video 1</a>      
      <a href="#" onclick="show(2);">Watch Video 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="popup" id="popup1">
      <video src="video1.mp4" controls></video>
      <img src="close.png" onclick="hide(1);" class="close" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="popup" id="popup2">
      <video src="video2.mp4" controls></video>
      <img src="close.png" onclick="hide(2);" class="close" alt="">
    </div>
  </section>
  <script>
    function show(id){
      var popup = document.querySelector("#popup" + id);
      var video = popup.querySelector("video");
      popup.classList.add("active");
      video.play();
    }

    function hide(id){
      var popup = document.querySelector("#popup" + id);
      var video = popup.querySelector("video");
      popup.classList.remove("active");
      video.pause();
      video.currentTime = 0;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just Added the unique IDs to each video popup div (e.g., "popup1" and "popup2").